# Can't access classes from different files in VB.NET Website

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I've inherited a VB.NET website and it won't compile because the `class1` in the file `class1.vb` refers to `class2` in a file called `class2.vb`. I get the following error when trying to compile:

> `Type Class2 is not defined.`

When I look in the object browser the classes are listed separately (i.e. not all grouped under the same namespace) and appear as:

```
Public Class Class 
    Inherits System.Object
     Member of C:\...\mywebsite\
```

#### Code:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Enum CountType
        Morning = 0
    End Enum
    Public Sub LogError(ByVal exp As Exception, ByVal err As ErrObject, _ 
                        ByVal sRoutine As String, _
                        Optional ByVal sMod As String = "")

    End Sub

End Class
```

#### `Class2.vb`

```
Public Class Class2

    Public Enum CountTypes
        Morning = 0
        Noon = 1
        Evening = 2
        Night = 3
        Other = 4
    End Enum

    Public Sub LogErrors(ByVal exp As Exception, _ 
                         ByVal err As ErrObject, _
                         ByVal sRoutine As String, _ 
                         Optional ByVal sMod As String = "")

    Dim cl As Class1   ' error here

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what the problem was with the project in Visual Studio. I ended up reverting the files in the folder to an earler visual studio project version of the project, letting VS convert to 2008, then getting latest from tfs and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If it's within the same project but in a different namespace make sure there is a using directive at the top to import the namespace you want access to

Comment: There is no namespaces directly on the classes, I guess they use the project default, it is like this:

Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Collections

Public Class DataAccess
...

Comment: I wrapped both files within a namespace statement and now in the object browser all the classes from both files appear grouped under the same namespace, but I still can't refer to a class from one file from the other file:

Namespace myspace
    Public Class Class2

Comment: As an edit to your original post, can you paste the class definitions for each? Everything from the top of the file, to the public class Class1/2 {}. The methods within each are unimportant.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem was with the project in Visual Studio. I ended up reverting the files in the folder to an earler visual studio project version of the project, letting VS convert to 2008, then getting latest from tfs and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You probably had a batch of errors after doing the conversion (one of them that the 'type is not defined' that you're trying to inherit from).

I recommend that you sort the errors by file name and check that there are no compile errors in the class you are trying to inherit from (as you can't inherit from a class with errors in it).